How to best respect safe area of 16px left/right: Inset design (16px to container) vs full width design (16px to content)
Background info

There is a discussion in our design team about 'inset' vs 'full width'. But we all wants to respect the safe area of 16px left and right on a mobile device.
Some people believe in 'inset' elements: 16px safe area is already needed from the edge of the screen to the container/card. As a result content is on 32px from the edge of the screen.
Others believe in 'full width' elements: only 16px safe area is needed from the edge to the screen to the content in the container/card. As a result the elements themselves can be full width.
Research shows that Apple uses a lot of inset list-items and elements in for example the setting page (gray background). Also a lot of 'new' apps are using cards and other inset elements. Material is also using full-width.
We have to deal with design system elements on both gray and white backgrounds. Read only text, list-items, radio and checkboxes all have a white background.
We have a mobile app and webapp.
Ideally there are no complex rules to remember what to do in which situation.

Examples

I added some examples below. In case of using 'inset' the gray page looks very nice to me, however the white version is using a lot of space left and right (32px on both sides).
In case of using 'full width' you can less clearly see the sections, because you have to rely on horizontal dividers only. Also we experience some problems with radiobuttons, because we highlight the full row. However, there is no space issue. You can solve the radiobutton problem by not changing the background and border, but that solution is less clear to me.

Question:

How to best respect the safe area of 16px left/right in our situation. What are the reasons to choose for inset vs full width design? Are there any usability problems with one or another?




I think your question is almost identical to this one: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/111710/cards-with-margins-vs-edge-to-edge-container

This question is similar to: Cards with margins VS Edge to Edge container. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This depends pretty much on two things mainly:

The nature of the real contents
taste, preference or applied style guide

The lorem ipsum does not really convey something to judge about the coherency of items on the screen (context/content information is missing).
In terms of space vs. visual appeal you have a clear trade-off I'd say:

Is visually more appealing (as a scribble, and probably on screen also)
Uses space more efficiently but also looks more "blocky".

The radio-button "problem" is none, or depends on the nature of the contents again. All alternatives are coherent with the safe-space approach taken. The full highlight background gives the radio button more visual impact. Question is: does the content make this necessary or not. Can't tell.
Debating over "small details" is a classic trope in design philosophy. It comes down to "If you have time for this, your app is probably (hopefully) already finished in the core functionality". My advise: Do not waste too much time and energy on it.

Because, honestly: Any of the approaches will do fine. There is no major broken concept needing to be avoided here. Also consider the costs of changing: We are talking about swapping 4 numbers in a CSS style-sheet probably, right?

Just pick one way and go with it until you have enough hard data which makes it necessary to change things. Then you have the backup you need to argument for one or the other approach. Without hard data, no (final) decision. It is hard and simple like that.

If you can't pick: I'd take #1. You can flip a coin also.


One important thing: Consult your style guide on this. If you have none, pick one or at least document important style decisions like this one, maybe with a solution strategy attached if the other approach should be applied at some time in the future.
